Routing fastest route with weighted paths in QGIS
My task is to assess pedestrian safety in urban areas by analyzing how many formal (pedestrian crossings, signal crossings etc) or informal (jaywalking/non-signal crossing) are along the shortest path in a network.
The algorithm should look for the shortest path but also take preference to using formal crossings. For example, if two crossings are available, take the Formal one.
But when no Formal crossings are available and the route needs to go across the street, it should use an Informal crossing. Informal and Formal crossings are both lines on a network but with their given attribute in the attributes table.
This should simulate real life, in the situation where one might take a pedestrian crossing if it's on the way but not if it means taking a detour to take it.
I have tried QNEAT3, and although it has functionality for one-way streets, it doesn't seem to have this weighting algorithm that I searched for.
Eventually, this would be automated since I have thousands of addresses and destinations.
I would prefer to stay within QGIS but if there is functionality within PGRouting SQL, Python, etc I wouldn't say no.
I have made a little map to help illustrate what I am trying to achieve.


In QNEAT3 as well as in the QGIS native tool Shortest path (point to point), you have an optional speed field. Speed in fact is a sort of a "cost" to reach from A to B: high speed = low cost (short time), low speed = high cost (longer travel time).
You could use an attribute with different values for formal (higher speed) and informal (smaller speed) crossings. All other lines have no (or default) speed.

Another approach would be rasterizing your line (buffer it a bit and create a raster pixel size that you have a thickness of at least three piels per line), then use raster least cost analysis (see here, especially Variant: prefer path in the middle of the polygon).

First solution: a network with four connected lines, each with a speed attribute (see label). Fastest path (highlighted in yellow) from start to end is along the red (speed: 16, "travelling by car") and dark blue (speed: 4, "bicycle") lines, even though along the green line, it would be shorter, but it has a speed of only 1 ("walking"). So taking a car and afterwards the bicycle and walking a very short rest is faster than walking the whole way, even if the distance is more direct:


The cost principle is sufficient to make it always take a formal crossing when one is available. Therefore should improve the results and should be able to filter out routes to schools where there are many informal crossings. Thank you

Yes, the cost principle is quite flexible as you could take into consideration different aspects that contribute to the value for the "cost" field and you could try out different setting of values for formal/informal crossings. And of course, it's an easy to implement solution.
